# Подружить OwlCarousel c NanoGallery2 и Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Доброго всем времени суток... собственно, задача сделать адаптивную галлерею внутри карусели и вроде бы все даже работает, НО!!! OwlCarusel при изменении размера браузера считает свои размеры блока, что портит всю картину и рушит сетку картинок... но после перезагрузки страницы все становится на свои места... Может кто так же с бубном танцевал? Буду очень признателен за любую помощь :-)))

[Пример тут](http://arempro.mcdir.ru/)